# How can I add onfocus() functionality in text field in sap ui5 instead of liveChange()

Tags: sapui5

How can I add onfocus() functionality in text field in sap ui5 instead of liveChange(), we have tried using onfocusin(), it is not working, suggest some more functionalities.

Comment: Extend the control with an `onfocusin` handler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58978363/5846045, especially if the control is supposed to be used multiple times (e.g. as a binding template in an XMLView definition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `attachBrowserEvent` method:

```
oYourTextControl.attachBrowserEvent("onfocus", function(oEvent) {
    // do whatever
});
```

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#attachBrowserEvent