# Best practice to register custom focus event handler for input fields

Tags: focus, sapui5

Sadly, I don't find any focus event for `sap.m.Input` or `sap.m.TextArea` to which I can register handlers in XML view.

What are your best practices e.g. if you have nearly 100 fields and most of them should handle **focus event so that the text within the input field gets automatically selected**?

Normally, I try to avoid to register the `focusin` handler in controller on every input field (also looping) but it seems that there are no other possibilities available isn't it?

What I want is a possibility, that when I navigate e.g. with keyboard through a table with input fields, every time when I press the <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>up</kbd><kbd>down</kbd> arrow keys to jump to next input field, **the whole content of the input field should be selected.**

Example:

1. Open this [table sample](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.Table/sample/sap.m.sample.TableEditable).
2. Click on <kbd>Edit</kbd>.
3. When tabbing, it automatically selects the text. But it doesn't work with <kbd>up</kbd><kbd>down</kbd> arrow keys and with `sap.m.Input` class.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of an extended `sap.m.Input` that selects the text on focus: **https://embed.plnkr.co/98BIbMEIujbzBXqU**

> ```js
> Input.extend("demo.control.Input", {
>   onfocusin: function() {
>     if (typeof Input.prototype.onfocusin == "function") {
>       Input.prototype.onfocusin.apply(this, arguments);
>     }
>     this.getDomRef("inner").select();
>   },
>   // ...
> });
> ```

**Note:** `sap.m.InputBase` provides the API `selectText(iStart, iEnd)`. However, that API doesn't support Input controls with type `Number` according to the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#input-type-attr-summary) as well as API reference:

> #### <sub>`selectText`</sub>
>
> Only supported for input control's type of `Text`, `Url`, `Tel` and `Password`.

Since our goal is to select **all** text within the input field (not a range) regardless of the type, `domElement.select()`<sup>[api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select)</sup> can be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a form with -- gasp! -- 100 fields, I would then extend the standard `sap.m.Input` and attach the `onfocus` browser event in that extended control using  `sap.ui.core.Control`'s [`attachBrowserEvent`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Control/methods/attachBrowserEvent) method.